# update media object programatically

Tags: 8, media

If I have the id of an existing piece of media content, what can I do to update it (modify it)?

I know how to create a new piece of media , (with Media::create) , but not sure of the code to load and then updated an existing piece of Media.

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Media is like any other entity based on [ContentEntityBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!ContentEntityBase.php/class/ContentEntityBase/8.2.x) in Drupal.

```
// top of your file
use Drupal\media_entity\Entity\Media;

// in a function
$media = Media::load($id);
// do stuff with $media
$media->save();
```

edit:

In a method of a class you would not want to use `Media::` but instead use `entityTypeManager` service to load the entity:

`$media = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('media')->load($id);` where `entityTypeManager` is injected to your class.

Comment: are there commands to set the data? such as setVid() , etc?

Comment: Check the docs for public methods.

Comment: $media->set('uid',$current_userid);

Comment: Yes. Check the class and what it is inheriting or extending - any of those public methods are available for you to use.

Comment: Now it's `use Drupal\media\Entity\Media;`